# Where is OutputStream Implementation

Tags: java, java-io

Well i wrote an app which would read from an socket connect using Outputstream. making a chain  using outputstream with OutputstreamWriter with BufferedWrittre with printwriter.
Now if i want to read a file in java i used the below method.

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:\\testnew\\out.text");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
String s;
while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
    System.out.println("s is "+s);

}
```

But in  a way  OutputStream seems to be missing. But since FileInputStream gives me object which helps me in reading content there should be internally 
  OutputStream implemented with in FileInputStream that is actually making things come up  on screen .

Comment: I don't understand question and problem !?

Answer (score 2):

Be clear about **OutputStream** and **InputStream**. THeir work is completely different. So there no question about one is implemented inside other.

**OutputStream** is used to **write** where as **FileInputStream** is used to **read**.

You will never find even a word of **OutputStream** in the source code of **FileInputStream**

Comment: Thank you for answer but.."OutputStream is used to write where as FileInputStream is used to read.".....i mean write where??
i have a scenarios i wrote a word in textfile using  FileInputStream

Answer (score 1):

> I think is it that OutputStream is implemented with in FileInputStream.

Precisely what's confusing you is not clear, but this is certainly wrong.

You're getting `s` from `fis` which is an `InputStream` and printing it through the `OutputStream` `System.out`, and they're completely separate.